# How to enqueue a function with an argument with Redis Queue?

Tags: python, redis, flask-socketio

I want to enqueue a function to run on background (using Redis Queue) and send a message to the client once the function is done, so I use Flask SocketIO using `send(msg)` after background task is done. Here the code

```js
# Server

@app.route("/update")
def update():
  job = q.enqueue(updateFiles) # Send function to background
  return render_template("index.html")

@socketio.on("message")
def updateFiles(msg): # Function running on background
  time.sleep(5)
  send(msg) # Sending message to the client after executing functions updateFiles

# HTML (jQuery):

socket.emit("message", "Files updated successfully"); // Emitting message to server
socket.on('message', function (msg) { // Receive message from server and show it on HTML template
  $("#message").html(msg);
});
```

On the server (Heroku) there is this error:

```html
2021-02-22T05:12:00.810166+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 719, in _execute
2021-02-22T05:12:00.810172+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
2021-02-22T05:12:00.810172+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: actualizarExpedientes() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
```

I see that the problem is `job = q.enqueue(updateFiles)`, because updateFiles requires an argument. The problem is that the argument `msg` comes from SocketIO, after emitting message with jQuery automatically. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From the [rq docs](https://python-rq.org/docs/)

```
q = Queue('low', connection=redis_conn)
q.enqueue(count_words_at_url,
          ttl=30,  # This ttl will be used by RQ
          args=('http://nvie.com',),
          kwargs={
              'description': 'Function description', # This is passed on to count_words_at_url
              'ttl': 15  # This is passed on to count_words_at_url function
          })
```

Just put your arguments in as the second argument when you call q.enqueue

```
 job = q.enqueue(updateFiles, msg)
```